# How to calculate mean of rows from excel spreadsheet instead of columns?

Tags: python, excel, row, mean

I have no idea how to calculate the means of all rows rather than all columns. I am using a large premade dataset with over 8000 rows and would like to find the mean of each in order to graph them all on one chart. I would not like to switch the rows to columns and vice versa unless that is my only option.

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(r'/Users/Admin/file.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2')

medians = df2.median(numeric_only=True)
means = df2.mean(numeric_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try `df.mean(axis=1)`.

`axis=1` would point to rows instead of columns